# Case-insensitive map key where key is Pair<String, String>

Tags: java, string, compare, case-insensitive

I have Map in Java:

```
 Map<Pair<String, String>, MyClass> myMap;
```

I need the Pair to **NOT** be case-sensitive. The solution in case of regular string key is simple:

```
 TreeMap<String, MyClass> myMap= new TreeMap(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

But, what about case of strings-pair key?

I need to compare `first` (left) value *case-sensitive* and then `second` (right) *case-insensitive*.

Comment: Which Pair class are you using? And which Map implementation?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - thanks, I will try write a comparator

Comment: @Eran - I'm not limited about it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I don't want to implement all methods of Map interface. How do I implement only comparator?

Comment: What property of `Pair` do want to compare? Left, right, or both? If both, what is the priority of left and right?

Comment: @user5260143 Then you can write a StringPair class, which will convert to lower case any String passes to it. Then you won't have to worry about the case. BTW, you only need to implement a Comparator (or your key type should implement Comparable) if you are using a TreeMap. If, instead, you are using a HashMap, your key type must override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: @Chaosfire - I need to compare them both, as what java does regulary.
But I need the second one to be case insensitive.

Comment: @Eran - thanks, this is also good idea. Currently I refer pass comparator but if it not success I'll use your idea.

Comment: @user5260143 And what is the comparison priority of both properties?

Comment: @Chaosfire the first is first, second is second

Comment: @user5260143 I would advise against using a comparator, and recommend instead Eran's suggestion. In particular, with the comparator approach you will make the comparison inconsistent with equals and hashCode, meaning that you will get surprising results for things like `containsKey`. Using a class that transforms your keys correctly is a better option.

Comment: In light of @AndyTurner's comment I removed my suggestion to implement a comparator.

Comment: @AndyTurner except that implementing a *correct* case insensitive hash code is a very tricky challenge.

Comment: @Holger if you store the lower-cased String (as Eran suggests), is it so hard?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, because it’s wrong. As [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78236814/java-not-case-sensitive-map-key-where-key-is-pairstring-string?noredirect=1#comment137930582_78236866), `equalsIgnoreCase` has different semantics than `toLowerCase()`. And when you start digging into the differences, you’ll realize the actual depth of the rabbit hole, as “case insensitive” has different meanings. If you do not want to care about the subtleties, `equalsIgnoreCase` is the way to go, but then, you don’t have a compatible `hashCode`. Otherwise, you need a refined task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)

> Accepts a function that extracts a Comparable sort key from a type T, and returns a Comparator that compares by that sort key.

and [`Comparator.thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)

> Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with a function that extracts a key to be compared with the given Comparator.

to easily build a comparator prioritizing `first` in comparison, and then `second` if `first` are equal.

```
Comparator<Pair> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Pair::first)//compare first case-sensitive
            .thenComparing(Pair::second, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);//case-insensitive comparison of second if first are equal
```

Comment: Instead of `.thenComparing((p1, p2) -> String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(p1.second(), p2.second()))` you actually want `.thenComparing(Pair::second, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` And to have both values case insensitive, `Comparator.comparing(Pair::first, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) .thenComparing(Pair::second, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`…

Comment: @Holger  OP wants to compare `first` normally (case-sensitive), at least that's how I interpret his comment - `I need to compare them both, as what java does regulary. But I need the second one to be case insensitive.`. But I will switch `.thenComparing()` as per your suggestion, it's much cleaner.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that clarification buried in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `TreeMap`, you can write a custom `Comparator` as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78236814/java-not-case-sensitive-map-key-where-key-is-pairstring-string#comment137929528_78236814) by [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca). See also the other answers on how to do this.
However, `TreeMap` should only be used if you really want your entries to by sorted by key.

If you don't need sorting, you can also create a custom key class with `hashCode` and `equals` methods and use a `HashMap`:

```java
record CaseInsensitiveStringPair(String first, String second){
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        return other instanceof CaseInsensitiveStringPair o &&
            first().toLowerCase().equals(o.first().toLowerCase()) &&
            second().toLowerCase().equals(o.second().toLowerCase()) 
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return Objects.hash(first().toLowerCase(), second().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

If it's ok if the `String`s are stored in lowercase form, you could do that as well:

```java
record CaseInsensitiveStringPair(String first, String second){
    public CaseInsensitiveStringPair(String first, String second){
        this.first=first.toLowerCase();
        this.second=second.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

and then use a

```java
Map<CaseInsensitiveStringPair, MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: My fault, I forgot to add `toLowerCase`. I fixed it.

Comment: Still incorrect. `new CaseInsensitiveStringPair("ı", "x")` and `new CaseInsensitiveStringPair("I", "X")` are `equal` but have different `hashCode`. Unfortunately, people keep coming up with “solutions” involving `toLowerCase()` and/or `toUpperCase()` when case insensitive matching is intended but it is both, horribly inefficient and incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I changed it to use lowercase consistently and it doesn't rely on `equalsIgnoreCase` any more.

Comment: Well, it’s still inefficient and bears a hidden dependency to the current default locale but at least, it’s consistent now…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your `Pair` object, unfortunately. However, I do know that TreeMap has a constructor with a `Comparator` parameter, so you can implement your own:

```
class CaseInsensitiveComparator implements Comparator<Pair<String, String>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair<String, String> o1, Pair<String, String> o2) {
        return o1.getKey().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getKey());
    }
}
```

and then you can simply do:

```
 Map<Pair<String, String>, MyClass> myMap = new TreeMap(new CaseInsensitiveComparator())
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to compare the two units of pair

Comment: @user5260143 Isn't that what the `Comparator` is this answer is doing?